# function st_intersects(bytea, bytea) is not unique

Tags: postgresql, postgis

When trying to combine two tables and export the result to a csv file, I am getting this error i.e. `function st_intersects(bytea, bytea) is not unique.`

[image: The whole screen after running the command and it also shows the tables that I am trying to combine.]

Comment: This image shows the whole error message and the two tables that I am trying to connect

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use the wrong data type (`bytea`) for your geometrical data.

PostgreSQL can convert between `bytea` and `geometry` / `geography` implicitly:

```
\dC bytea
                         List of casts
   Source type   | Target type |      Function      | Implicit? 
-----------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------
 bytea           | geography   | geography          | yes
 bytea           | geometry    | geometry           | yes
 geography       | bytea       | bytea              | yes
 geometry        | bytea       | bytea              | yes
[...]
(7 rows)
```

Now there are three functions `st_intersects`:

```
\df st_intersects
                                  List of functions
 Schema |     Name      | Result data type |       Argument data types        | Type 
--------+---------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------
 public | st_intersects | boolean          | geog1 geography, geog2 geography | func
 public | st_intersects | boolean          | geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry   | func
 public | st_intersects | boolean          | text, text                       | func
(3 rows)
```

Now following its [function type resolution rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html), PostgreSQL has no way to determine if you want the first or the second of these functions, which causes the error message.

**Solutions:**

1. Use the appropriate data type (`geometry` or `geography`) in your table definitions.
2. Use an explicit cast, like the error message tells you:

   ```
   st_intersects(CAST (g1 AS geometry), CAST (g2 AS geometry))
   ```

I think it was a bad choice of PostGIS to make both casts implicit.